# Coding Theory - Probability that word received has distance of at most 1?

Tags: probability, coding-theory

Suppose the codeword x = 101101 is transmitted over the binary symmetric
channel, with symbol error probability p.

What is the probability that the word received has distance at most 1 from x?
Justify your answer.

This was my approach:
\begin{align*}
P &= P(\mathrm{less \; than \; or \; equal \; to \; 1 \; bit \; error}) \\ &= 1-P(\mathrm{greater  \; than \;or \;equal \;to \;2\; bit \;errors}) \\ &= 1- (P(2 \;\mathrm{errors}) + P (3 \;\mathrm{errors}) + P (4 \;\mathrm{errors}) + P (5 \;\mathrm{errors}) + P (6\; \mathrm{errors})) \\&=1- \left({6 \choose2}p^2 (1-p)^4 + {6 \choose3} p^3 (1-p)^3 + {6 \choose4} p^4 (1-p)^2 + {6 \choose5} p^5 (1-p) + {6 \choose6}p^6\right)
\end{align*}

Then I got stuck and couldn't figure out an approach to go from here. Is this correct or on the right track? Or am I absolutely wrong and overdoing this?

Comment: It's correct, but it would be a lot easier to evaluate:
$$\Pr(X\le 1) = \Pr(X = 0) + \Pr(X = 1),$$ where $X\sim \mathcal{B}(6,p)$ is the random variable that expresses the number of errors.

Comment: Okay thanks and then would the equation look like:
[(6C0)p^0 (1-p) + (6C1) p^1] ?

Comment: You missed the factor $(1-p)^5$ in the second summand.

Comment: Does that also mean is should (1-p)^6 on the first summand? Sorry a little confused as to what the final equation should  look like?

Comment: Yes, you are right! It seems I overlooked that, as well!

Comment: I assume that the expression "distance at most 1" means the received signal differs from the signal $x = 101101$ at 1 digit at most. Right? All the above hold under that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each position, there is probability $p$ that there is an error in that position, and probability $(1-p)$ that there is not an error in that position.  So for example, the probability that there is an error in the first position and no others is $p \cdot (1-p)^{5}$.  How many possible ways can you have a single error? As mentioned in the comments, $(1-p)^6$ gives the probability of no errors. This should lead to a solution. (this is much more efficient than computing 1- P(2 or more errors)).